# td width not apply when table wrapped with div with specific width and overflow is applied

Tags: html, css

With the below html, I am not able to add width of td element

here table is wrapped with div and it's width is 200px and overflow-x is given.

```html
<div class="scroll" style="width: 200px; overflow-x: overlay;">

<table class="scrollable">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td width="100" data-index="0" style="width: 118px;">-0.29%</td>
    <td data-index="1">-0.26%</td>
    <td data-index="2">-0.20%</td><td data-index="3">-0.15%</td>
    <td data-index="4">-0.09%</td><td data-index="5">0.19%</td>
    <td data-index="6">0.54%</td><td data-index="7">0.95%</td>
    <td data-index="8">1.33%</td><td data-index="9">1.67%</td>
    <td data-index="10">1.97%</td><td data-index="11">2.22%</td>
    <td data-index="12">2.44%</td><td data-index="13">2.62%</td>
    <td data-index="14">2.78%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the display property of `<td>` to `display:inline-block`.
Also you should add this `table { width: max-content; }` to your CSS so your table can fit all the `<td>` now that they are bigger.

```css
table {
  width: max-content;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll" style="
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
">
  <table class="scrollable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-index="0">-0.29%</td>
        <td data-index="1">-0.26%</td>
        <td data-index="2">-0.20%</td>
        <td data-index="3">-0.15%</td>
        <td data-index="4">-0.09%</td>
        <td data-index="5">0.19%</td>
        <td data-index="6">0.54%</td>
        <td data-index="7">0.95%</td>
        <td data-index="8">1.33%</td>
        <td data-index="9">1.67%</td>
        <td data-index="10">1.97%</td>
        <td data-index="11">2.22%</td>
        <td data-index="12">2.44%</td>
        <td data-index="13">2.62%</td>
        <td data-index="14">2.78%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: if you apply to all td, that all td will be stacked. see https://jsfiddle.net/nzge6vk5/1/